# How can I populate a div with Rails code when a link is clicked?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to populate some `li` tags with this code:

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <li>
    <span class="eventname"><%= event.name %></span>
    <span class="eventlocation"><%= event.location %></span>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

And I have some links that say "today", "tomorrow" etc and when I hit today I want the events from today to show up.  If I hit tomorrow I want tomorrow's to show up.  I've looked everywhere through AJAX tutorials and javascript tutorials and I'm completely lost on how to do this in rails.

One way I considered doing is having this block of code be a partial, and change it slightly for each partial so that the specific events that I want to show come up.  But then I'm still stuck with the same problem, I'm not sure how to show a specific partial based on the click of a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will have one partial that would render a set of given events (any type) let's call it `_events.html.erb`

**_events.html.erb:**

```
<% events.each do |event| %>
  <li>
    <span class="eventname"><%= event.name %></span>
    <span class="eventlocation"><%= event.location %></span>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Then we would create an action named `fetch_events` that returns a js response.

```
Class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def fetch_events
    @events = Event.where(type: params[:type])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

ofcourse in routes.rb

`match 'fetch_events/:type' => 'events#fetch_events', as: :fetch_events`

now we build out `fetch_events.js.erb`, this file will set the contents of the div with id 'events' to the rendered partial.

**fetch_events.js.erb:**

```
$('#events').html(<%= escape_javascript(render :events, events: @events) %>)
```

Now in your page view add a have div with id 'events' that will contain the response, while
the ajax could be called using `link_to`

```
<%= link_to 'today', fetch_events_path(type: :today),  :remote => true %>
<%= link_to 'tomorrow', fetch_events_path(type: :tomorrow),  :remote => true %>
```

Comment: I don't know if SO is doing it but your ERB tags are wrong inside the loop for the partial. It is also worth noting that you would need to trigger an AJAX request once the filter is selected. But this is the money answer here.

Comment: I fixed the erb tag of the loop. Thanks

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for! A quick question though (well, 2 really):  where does the .js.erb file go, and how is an AJAX request triggered?  By an AJAX request does he mean a <%= link_to 'sometext' :method => :fetch_events %> type deal?

Comment: the .js.erb file will be in the view folder of events controller, check this cast for more on js response http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript,
I just added the ajax part to the answer.

Comment: another quick question, i attempted the solution given by Khaled and I am getting an error in the controller, at @events = Event.where(type: params[:type]).  It says "unexpected :, expecting ;".  I'm also curious what this line of code even does, as I've never used an "Event.where" before

Comment: `@events = Event.where(type: params[:type])` this line is just an example of how you could fetch events that belong to certain type(assuming your event has attribute named type), it could be different in your application. You could fetch the events in any other way that works.
`Event.where` would select events that meet certain conditions.

Comment: Got it thanks.  And in terms of the link_to methods, I'm supposing that if I'm not using any sort of "type" attribute, I could just say "fetch_events_path()".  However that doesn't seem to work either - I'm guessing I need to add something to my routes.rb file but I'm not sure what to add